# Using libgdx in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, libgdx

I'm trying to make libgdx desktop application using IntelliJ (ver. 15) and I followed the instructions here:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-Intellij-IDEA

But when I tried to run the Desktop luncher I got this exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mygdx.game.desktop.DesktopLauncher

So I looked at google and the solution I found was to execute some "run" script of the desktop under the Gradle tab. This is the solution:
[libgdx ClassNotFoundException when starting Desktop main - Mac, IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15413501/libgdx-classnotfoundexception-when-starting-desktop-main-mac-intellij/34154999#34154999)

And it worked. But right now every time I make a change in my code, the change doesn't update if I run using the "Desktop" application. It's updated only when I'm running using the script again (change the "run" configurations to "MyGame:desktop[run]").
Does someone has a solution?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure your run configuration has "build" has a dependency

Comment: Sounds like you need Gradle to recompile the project and replace the desktop launcher

Comment: @Winter can you be more specific? I didn't see at the run configuration something with "build".  Also I tried to rebuild it with the provided Gradle but didn't help

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/ywVMx But most likely its not that problem